# pom.xml compilation issue in spring boot and reactjs

Tags: spring, reactjs, spring-boot

I am getting compilation error in pom.xml.I am using spring boot with reactjs.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>bg.proxiad.courses.web</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-react-demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>spring-react-demo</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot with ReactJS</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    <frontend.version>1.3</frontend.version>
    <node.version>v6.10.0</node.version>
    <npm.version>3.10.10</npm.version>

    <shiro-spring.version>1.3.2</shiro-spring.version>
    <springfox.version>2.6.1</springfox.version>
    <apache.commons.lang.version>3.0</apache.commons.lang.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${springfox.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/frontend/build</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${frontend.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <workingDirectory>src/main/frontend</workingDirectory>
                <nodeVersion>${node.version}</nodeVersion>
                <npmVersion>${npm.version}</npmVersion>
                <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>npm install</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>install</arguments>
                        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>webpack build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>run-script build</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`
Here is my error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type Execution npm install of goal
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm failed: A required
>   class was missing while executing
>   com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm:
>   Lorg/eclipse/aether/RepositorySystemSession;
>   ----------------------------------------------------- realm =    plugin>com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3 strategy =
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy urls[0] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/1.3/frontend-maven-plugin-1.3.jar
>   urls[1] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/frontend-plugin-core/1.3/frontend-plugin-core-1.3.jar
>   urls[2] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-mapper-asl/1.9.13/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   urls[3] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/jackson/jackson-core-asl/1.9.13/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
>   urls[4] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-compress/1.5/commons-compress-1.5.jar
>   urls[5] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/tukaani/xz/1.2/xz-1.2.jar
>   urls[6] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
>   urls[7] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5.1/httpclient-4.5.1.jar
>   urls[8] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.3/httpcore-4.4.3.jar
>   urls[9] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2/commons-logging-1.2.jar
>   urls[10] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.9/commons-codec-1.9.jar
>   urls[11] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
>   urls[12] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
>   urls[13] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus/0.0.0.M2a/org.eclipse.sisu.plexus-0.0.0.M2a.jar
>   urls[14] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/javax/enterprise/cdi-api/1.0/cdi-api-1.0.jar
>   urls[15] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/jsr250-api/1.0/jsr250-api-1.0.jar
>   urls[16] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar
>   urls[17] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava/10.0.1/guava-10.0.1.jar
>   urls[18] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
>   urls[19] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/sisu/sisu-guice/3.1.0/sisu-guice-3.1.0-no_aop.jar
>   urls[20] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar
>   urls[21] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/eclipse/sisu/org.eclipse.sisu.inject/0.0.0.M2a/org.eclipse.sisu.inject-0.0.0.M2a.jar
>   urls[22] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/asm/asm/3.3.1/asm-3.3.1.jar
>   urls[23] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
>   urls[24] =
>   file:/C:/Users/UserPC/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
>   Number of foreign imports: 4 import: Entry[import
>   org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm
>   ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import
>   org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core,
>   parent: null]] import: Entry[import
>   org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm
>   ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]] import: Entry[import  from
>   realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
>
> -----------------------------------------------------  (com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.3:npm:npm
>   install:generate-resources)   pom.xml /spring-react-demo  line 103    Maven
>   Build Problem

Kindly look into this and help me to resolve.Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Do the following things:

1. Clean the project.
2. Run As -> Maven clean.
3. Maven -> update project -> check "Force update" option
4. Run As -> Maven install